# How can i open netcdf data with float precision using xaray?

Tags: python, netcdf

I'm using CRU data and every time i try to create a data array the variable values are filled with "NON", ".0" or "-" so i can't use them to calculate statistics.

I tried to convert the variables to Double precision and to open the data with the netcdf4 library but i had no luck.